# Error in solving trigonometric functions using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, trigonometry

```
import math

number = input('Your Number: ')
ways = input('sin/cos/tan: ')

try:
    problem = ways(number)
    answer = math.problem
    print(f'The value of {ways} of {number} is: {problem}')
```

This is my code.

I want to solve trigonometric functions using math module in python but every time I run it it gives me an error `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: ```ways``` is a string, not a function

Comment: `try` can't stand with out accompanying `except` statement

Comment: so what can i do, to covert it into function

Comment: i think variable ways is string type.. you can use if else statements, and check if ways == sin, use sin, likewise..

Answer (score 1):

I tried to avoid completely your problem with `try` `except` using a slightly different logic for testing the validity of the input.

Also, I've used the canonical solution for mapping a string to a function at run time, i.e., using a mapping (in Python,a `dict`).

Here it is my solution, complete with a little test run.

```
In [6]: import math 
   ...: trigs = {'sin':math.sin, 'cos':math.cos, 'tan':math.tan} 
   ...: while True: 
   ...:     try:
   ...:         number = input('Your Number: ')
   ...:         fnumber = float(number) 
   ...:         break 
   ...:     except ValueError: 
   ...:         print('You input a non-valid floating point number.\nPlease try again') 
   ...:         continue 
   ...: while True: 
   ...:     trig = input('sin/cos/tan: ') 
   ...:     if trig in trigs: break 
   ...:     print('You input a non-valid trig function.\nPlease try again') 
   ...:  
   ...: print(f'The value of {trig} of {number} is: {trigs[trig](fnumber)}')              
Your Number: ret
You input a non-valid floating point number.
Please try again
Your Number: 1.57
sin/cos/tan: ert
You input a non-valid trig function.
Please try again
sin/cos/tan: tan
The value of tan of 1.57 is: 1255.7655915007897

In [7]:
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should have a `except` block, which does at least error handling even `pass`
- `ways` is actually function, take different input

```
import math

number = input('Your Number: ')
ways_ = input('sin/cos/tan: ')

try:
    problem = ways(number)
    answer = math.problem
    print(f'The value of {ways} of {number} is: {number}')
except:
    pass
    # anything else?? handle errors??
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add the `except` block for handling exceptions in case something goes wrong in your code.
2. You could write a code like this for achieving your desired task:

```
import math
number = input('Your Number: ')
ways = input('sin/cos/tan: ')

def math_func(num, type_func):
    func = {'sin': lambda: math.sin(num),
            'cos': lambda: math.cos(num),
            'tan': lambda: math.tan(num)}
    return func.get(type_func)()

try:
    answer = math_func(float(number), ways)
    print(f'The value of {ways} of {number} is: {answer}')
except:
    pass
```